# Serialize non model class in django

Tags: django, json, serialization, jsonserializer

i have a class (non model)

```
from django.utils import simplejson
class myclass:
    def __init(self):
        self.x = "1877"
        self.y = "1410"
        self.z = "400"
        self.w = "67"
        self.a ="0"
        self.b = "1"
        self.c = "319996"
        self.d ="187702"
        self.t = "168000"

def ajaxRes(request):
    mobj = myclass;
    json_str = simplejson.dumps(mobj)
    return HttpResponse(json_str,mimetype ="application/x-javascript")
```

i got the follwoing error :

`class myapp.views.myclass at 0x7faadc020c18> is not JSON serializable`

I also tried the serializers of django but it seems only work for model class

```
from django.core import serializers
data = serializers.serialize("json", mobj.objects.all())
```

throws error that `mobj` does not have any attribute objects.

How can one serialize a class in `django [json format]`.

Comment: This is not that easy: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/4822098/146283

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to prepare simplejson serializer to handle your class:

```
from django.utils import simplejson

class HandleMyClass(simplejson.JSONEncoder):
     """ simplejson.JSONEncoder extension: handle MyClass"""
     def default(self, obj):
         if isinstance(obj, MyClass):
             return obj.__dict__
         return simplejson.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)

data = simplejson.dumps( dictionary, cls=HandleMyClass )
```